# Matrix representation of a 6-dimensional Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, invariant-theory

**The question is about the matrix representation of the following 6-dimensional Lie algebra**, with 6 generators $t_1,t_2,t_3,t_4,t_5,t_6$. This Lie algebra is nilpotent, non-abelian, non-reductive and solvable. The commutation relations between all the generators are:

$$[t_1,t_2]=t_6,$$ 
$$[t_2,t_3]=t_4,$$ 
$$[t_3,t_1]=t_5,$$ 
while all the other commutators are zeros.

The invariants of this Lie algebra is found to be $t_4,t_5,t_6$ and $t_1t_4+t_2t_5+t_3t_6$.

**Questions: What are the allowed matrix representation of the above 6-dimensional Lie algebra? What are the rank of the matrices of the representation?**

The Ref is TABLE III in [Invariants of real low dimension Lie algebras
J. Patera, R. T. Sharp, P. Winternitz, and H. Zassenhaus
Citation: Journal of Mathematical Physics 17, 986 (1976); doi: 10.1063/1.522992](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.522992). I had switch the notations from $e_1 \to t_1,e_2 \to t_2,e_3 \to t_3,
e_5 \to t_4,e_4 \to -t_5,e_6 \to t_6$ for a more symmetric form.

[image]

Comment: By the way, viewed as a complex Lie algebra, this radical of the (parabolic) stabilizer of null $3$-plane in $SO(7, \Bbb C)$ (in the real case we can replace the group with $SO(3, 4)$).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "invariants." Can you clarify? Do you mean these elements are central in the universal enveloping algebra?

Comment: @ Qiaochu Yuan: The invariant is related to the symmetric bilinear form which replaces the usual Killing form -- because the Lie algebra is not semi-simple; it is non-semi-simple. If you write down the symmetric bilinear form it has the t1t4+t2t5+t3t6 off-diagonal coupling term.

Comment: I have computed the faithful matrix representations of minimal degree of this algebra. What do you mean by "allowed" ? Which one are forbidden ?

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde. Any faithful matrix representations of minimal degree of this algebra will do the job to answer this question.

Comment: Dear @Idear. Try to compute such a representations as described [here](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214823/faithful-linear-representation-of-a-nilpotent-lie-algebra/214825#214825); this is straightforward (try degree $6$ first), and also works for non-filiform algebras like $A_{6,3}$.